# Select string before some letters

Tags: javascript, jquery

If I have

```
var x = "3558&Hello world!&538345";
```

Now for selecting after I can use:

```
var y = x.split("&");
```

But I want to know can I select it before some char?

I need to get  `var z = 3558`... 
I don't want to select letters and nums from 0 to 4 because I don't know what is the length of numbers.... So is there any way to say select all before & ?

Comment: y[0] = first index, y[y.length] = last index

Comment: `var z = x.split('&').shift();`

Comment: the `.split()` function returns an array of values (it uses the `&`, in this case, as the separator)

Comment: Yeah I saw smething similar in moment and now I am trying that with 0 :D But thanks :D

Comment: But can I use & inside id?

Answer (score 1):

You're using the split functionality, so just grab the value at position 0 of the resulting array, that will be the substring up until the first &.

```
var y = x.split ("&")[0];
```

Comment: var x = "3558&Hello world!&538345";
x.substring(0,x.indexOf('&'));

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
var y = x.split('&')[0]; // y = "3558"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `String.prototype.replace()` with `RegExp` `/&.+/` to match `"&"` and characters that follow, replace match with empty string

```
var z = "3558&Hello world!&538345".replace(/&.+/, "")
```

Comment: will work for `target&ok` [but not for](https://regex101.com/#javascript) `target&`. Use `.*` not `.+`

Answer (score 0):

Lots of options! :D

```
function bySplit (textStr, delimiterStr) {
  return textStr.split(delimiterStr)[0]
}
```

---

```
function byRegexReplace (textStr, delimiterStr) {
  return textStr.replace(new RegExp(delimiterStr+'.*'), '')
}
```

---

```
function byRegexExec (textStr, delimiterStr) {
  return (new RegExp('^(.*)'+delimiterStr)).exec(textStr)[1]
}
```

You could also write `for` or `while` loop to add chars to a result unless they encounter a matching delimiterStr, but they get messy compared to these three.